# How to print 'forall' as 'Π' in a one-time setting in coqdoc?

Tags: coq

I was able to get coqdoc to print `forall` as `Π`, using `(** printing forall %Π% #Π# *)`. However, it is a pain to add the description to all the files. Is it possible to do that for all files with just one setting?

Note that I have to use `-utf8`, because I am writing a document with characters that are not part of ASCII. That may have something to do with it.